# Time series forecasting. How use future values

Tags: time-series, regression, lstm, pytorch, forecasting

I have a time series dataset containing hourly data from a few year, like below. Let's assume that I want to make prediction for the next 3 hours (2021-01-01 19:00, 2021-01-01 20:00, 2021-01-01 21:00). The output from model (e.g. LSTM) is the following sequence: [Feature_1(t+1), Feature_1(t+2), Feature_1(t+3)]. One of the features of my training data is weather data.

| Date | Feature_1 | Weather_feature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 15:00 | value(t0) | value(t0) |
| 2019-01-01 16:00 | value(t0) | value(t0) |
| .... | ... | ... |
| 2021-01-01 18:00 | value(t0) | value(t0) |

Can I use data, that I already know in my model? I would like to use the weather forecast for the next hours to improve my predctions.
For example at `2021-01-01 18:00` i know value `Feature_1` and  `Weather_feature` in time `t(0)` but also i know already `Weather_feature` in `(t+1)`, `(t+2)`, `(t+3)`. How can i use it in the model?

At the moment, this is what one training sample looks like: `[[Feature_1(t-n), Weather_feature(t-n)]...[Feature_1(t-1),Weather_feature(t-1), [Feature_1(t0), Weather_feature(t0)]]`

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution or some literature ? Thanks !